# Why Do Binary Tree Traversals need a helper function?

Tags: java, binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

```
class Solution {
    private void preorderTraversal(TreeNode root, List<Integer> answer) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        answer.add(root.val);                   
        preorderTraversal(root.left, answer);   
        preorderTraversal(root.right, answer);  
    }
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        preorderTraversal(root, answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Why do i need a helper function?

I tried implementing the traversal using only one function.I expected this to work without any additional helper function.

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();

        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        answer.add(root.val);                   
        preorderTraversal(root.left, answer);   
        preorderTraversal(root.right, answer);  
        return answer;

}
```

Comment: In your version, you call `preorderTraversal(root.left, answer)`, but you never define a version of `preorderTraversal` that accepts a list.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt calls the function recursively with 2 arguments, but there is no function with that signature.

Note also that your base case `return` is not valid, as your function is supposed to return an ArrayList, so do `return answer;`.

It is however possible to do it without helper function. You should then capture the returned ArrayList from the recursive calls, and add those contents to your current ArrayList:

```
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        if (root == null) return answer;
        answer.add(root.val);                  
        answer.addAll(preorderTraversal(root.left));   
        answer.addAll(preorderTraversal(root.right));  
        return answer;
    }
```

But this is not so memory efficient as the version with the helper function, which only needs *one* ArrayList and no values need to be copied from one ArrayList to another.